# Is this Purge valve ticking sound normal? Youtube video

Tags: engine, corolla, p0171

It is 2001 Corolla 1.8 engine. I'm still in the process of diagnosing an intermittent P0171 code. I posted a video in other post and user Carguy was very helpful and he mentioned that this ticking sound not normal and asked me to check where is it coming from and found it was the purge valve clicking constantly after the engine gets warm on idle. I went to a junk yard and got a used one for cheap just to make sure that i don't have a faulty solenoid. After replacing it the same continuous clicking is generated. [Here is a youtube link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C5bsBYUvxIU) around 0.12 in video that sound is more audible. Is this normal?
Thanks.

Comment: Yah, I'm thinking this is a normal sound, but I am not positive. I've heard purge valves and the like (ie: EGR) make the same kinds of noises before. Some of them are just noisy.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  I still have a lot to learn!

Comment: One more question. Based on the vacuum test, it is not a vacuum issue and do not need to go down rabbit hole check hoses and intake gasket as the test showed that the system creating a normal vacuum in the green range area using the gauge right?